# Nifi expression language for postgres "insert into" single quote varchars

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I am trying to use nifi expression for

`INSERT INTO public.demo (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (?,?,?) ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE set col2 = '${sql.args.2.value:replaceAll("*regex for single quote*","regex for double quote ")}'`

So col2 is in a Oracle database often having a single quote.

Ex. " user's " which is creating problems for postgres insertion as postres uses a single quote to start and end varchar values.

I read about nifi expression language and am using it like the above but its throwing a syntax error.
What should it be like?
I guess I also need to be replacing the ? In values With the same sql.args.

Comment: So if this is for Oracle why the Postgres tag?

Comment: The data is being read from Oracle and transported to postgres. My bad, drafted this after a frustrating day. Am changing it

Comment: So what is the driver/interface you are using to get the data into Postgres? Also how are you getting it out of Oracle?

Comment: Try to troubleshoot using `'${sql.args.2.value:replaceAll('\'','\'\'')'`

Comment: Am using the postgres 10 driver .

Comment: An getting it out of Oracle using the "select * " query , splitting that json and upserting it into postgres 10

Comment: This is the first you have mentioned there is JSON involved. You need to create a complete example of what you are doing and add to your question.